# can someone explain me the 'local maximum' approach used in the given github link?

Tags: image-processing, keyframe

i am currently working on a project on image processing.
i came to see this code on extracting key frames from a video.
however i cannot understand the function smooth() used in the code.

```py
def smooth(x, window_len=13, window='hanning'):
    """smooth the data using a window with requested size.

    This method is based on the convolution of a scaled window with the signal.
    The signal is prepared by introducing reflected copies of the signal 
    (with the window size) in both ends so that transient parts are minimized
    in the begining and end part of the output signal.

    input:
        x: the input signal 
        window_len: the dimension of the smoothing window
        window: the type of window from 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman'
            flat window will produce a moving average smoothing.
    output:
        the smoothed signal

    example:
    import numpy as np    
    t = np.linspace(-2,2,0.1)
    x = np.sin(t)+np.random.randn(len(t))*0.1
    y = smooth(x)

    see also: 

    numpy.hanning, numpy.hamming, numpy.bartlett, numpy.blackman, numpy.convolve
    scipy.signal.lfilter

    TODO: the window parameter could be the window itself if an array instead of a string   
    """
    logger.info("length of frames: %d" % len(x))
    # if x.ndim != 1:
    #     raise ValueError, "smooth only accepts 1 dimension arrays."
    #
    # if x.size < window_len:
    #     raise ValueError, "Input vector needs to be bigger than window size."
    #
    # if window_len < 3:
    #     return x
    #
    # if not window in ['flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman']:
    #     raise ValueError, "Window is on of 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman'"

    s = np.r_[2 * x[0] - x[window_len:1:-1],
              x, 2 * x[-1] - x[-1:-window_len:-1]]
    #print(len(s))

    if window == 'flat':  # moving average
        w = np.ones(window_len, 'd')
    else:
        w = getattr(np, window)(window_len)
    y = np.convolve(w / w.sum(), s, mode='same')
    return y[window_len - 1:-window_len + 1]
```

the link to the github page is:

https://github.com/abner-gong/video-keyframes-extraction-python-package/blob/master/KeyFrames.py

any kind of help would be appreciated.thank you.

Comment: what exactly you don't understand ? do you understand what is a convolution ?

Comment: yes i do understand convolution. but i cannot understand the part where we divide the input array and store it in the variable 's'

Comment: So if you mean the line s = np.r_.... it has been wrote to handle borders problem (because convolution on the borders/limits of an array require to have data outside of the array). Thus they merge the data 'x' with some data before and after x to be able to convolve on the borders.  There is multiple strategies but I don't know that one ^^ you may have a look here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_Handling

Comment: thanx man.really helpful